# How to fixed the button in navigation bar on scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4

I have 6 fields in my navbar. 5 of them are links and one is dropdown. When I scroll the page all field remains fixed except the dropdown field.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnT9R.png)

[image]

Below is my code:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Food-fair-toggle">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pricing">menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#featured-dish">featured</a></li>
    <li><a href="#reserve">reservation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="https://deliveroo.nl/">Deliveroo</a>
          <a href="https://www.foodora.nl/">Foodora</a>
          <a href="https://www.ubereats.com//">UberEats</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: can you add your css code too? It will be helpful

Comment: You can possible to change the div structure. I have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below menu bar along with the dropdown menus.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below HTML, JS and CSS. Just change  structure, create separate  for dropdown with same class. Then you must add id attribute for menu UL.

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Food-fair-toggle">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="myHeader">
    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pricing">menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#featured-dish">featured</a></li>
    <li><a href="#reserve">reservation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>    
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="https://deliveroo.nl/">Deliveroo</a>
          <a href="https://www.foodora.nl/">Foodora</a>
          <a href="https://www.ubereats.com//">UberEats</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

Copy & paste the JS in footer section.

```
<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
      } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
ul.sticky {
    position: fixed !important;
    background: #27752A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Example shows how to add dropdown menu in bootstrap-4 navbar.

And if you want to fix the navbar on top, then you can add `class='fixed-top'` in `<nav>` component then menu will stick to the top while you scroll down.

Or if you dont want navbar menu fixed on top then you can remove that class `fixed-top` from navbar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="bg-success navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
  

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">MENU</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#featured-dish">FEATURED</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#reserve">RESERVATION</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
    </li>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        DROPDOWN
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://deliveroo.nl/">Deliveroo</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.foodora.nl/">Foodora</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ubereats.com//">UberEats</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<br>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
  <p>This example adds a dropdown menu in the fixed navbar on Top,This example adds a dropdown menu in the fixed navbar on Top, This example adds a dropdown menu in the fixed navbar on Top, This example adds a dropdown menu in the fixed navbar on Top, This example adds a dropdown menu in the fixed navbar on Top.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please read the question, They don't need the sticky menu for all link. Don't sticky this <li class="nav-item dropdown">

Comment: @stalinrajindian He has written that when I scroll all field remains fixed , so I have given answer as per that, and I have also told that if you don't want sticky menu then you can remove fixed-top class from nav tag

Comment: perhaps he is not asking for sticky menu , so i have updated my answer, thanks for commenting about it @stalinrajindian.